# gfoldl / Data.Data.Data instance for HLists without unsafeCoerce

Tags: haskell

The Data class mentions the `c` type variable only in the method so it seems I cannot mention it in the constraint on the instance.

```
gfoldl :: Data a =>
  (forall d b. Data d => c (d -> b) -> d -> c b)
   -> (forall g. g -> c g)
   -> a
   -> c a
```

I can write a foldl for my HList, but the constraint ends up including the `c`,
so one solution is to replace the `c` with a concrete `data C a`.

```
instance (HBuild' '[] g,
        Typeable (HList a),
        HFoldl (GfoldlK C) (C g) a (C (HList a)))
  => Data (HList a) where

    gfoldl k z xs = c3 $ hFoldl
                                (c1 (GfoldlK k))
                                (c2 (z hBuild))
                                xs
        where
              c1 :: forall c a. GfoldlK c -> GfoldlK C
              c1 = unsafeCoerce

              c2 :: forall c. c g -> C g
              c2 = unsafeCoerce

              c3 :: forall c. C (HList a) -> c (HList a)
              c3 = unsafeCoerce
```

This seems to work. But is there a solution
without the unsafecoerces? The full code is here: http://lpaste.net/93565